# When is $(1^2+1)(2^2+1)\dots (n^2+1)$ a perfect square?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Find all such $n$. Natural guess is that $n=3$ is the only solution.

It is natural to try something like Bertrand's postulate for Gaussian integers with imaginary part 1, but what is known?

Comment: Is there any history to this question?

Comment: @IgorRivin as you see, history exists

Comment: @AlexeyUstinov indeed, then I delete it